# Distance Problem WITHOUT Calculus

Tags: optimization, word-problem

The problem is: Suppose you have two points above a horizontal line. You draw a line from from the first point to the line and draw a line from the intersection of the first point and the horizontal line to the second point. How do you minimize the distance of the two line segments?
I can't figure out how to do this without calculus. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Answered in comments

Comment: Let the points above the given  horizontal line $\ell$ be $A$ and $B$. Reflect $B$ in $\ell$, obtaining $B'$. Join $A$ and $B'$. Where the line segment $AB'$ meets $\ell$ is where on $\ell$  we should go to (a line gives the shortest distance between two points).

Comment: This problem has been on MSE before, probably more than once.

Comment: Well thanks anyway

Comment: You are welcome. I hope the brief comment was enough for you to construct the argument. There is a nice book by Ivan Niven, *Maxima and Minima without Calculus*.